# HDD disk is turning off after wrong amount of idle time

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, power

Since few days my (very loud) secondary disk is turning off after 5-10 minutes idle, when in power settings I have set only 2 minutes.

I have checked in "Process Monitor" app and nothing is using it. Anyone know if there are other settings which are determining this idle time?

With regards, Arkadiusz

Comment: Are you sure the disk is idle after those 2 minutes, because it seems, that its taking slightly longer for the drive to enter an idle state.  I assume you have used this feature here ( http://superuser.com/questions/658112/setting-hdd-turn-off-per-disk?rq=1 ) to set the idle time?

Comment: Process Monitor does not show pagefile.sys and various $Xxx file accesses by default. Could that be a point?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I've used it. And I've measured it few times, the between my last use of disc and turning off was always around 5:30-5:50 seconds.
               ThomasW.: I have deleted this filter so it showed me everything.